# PostgreSQL importing CSV files in two phases with a single script (psycopg2)

Tags: python, database, postgresql, csv

I'm a little bit confused as I need to import one batch of csv files into a PostgreSQL database in the first phase , and then add another batch in the second phase. For example the second phase csv's are the additional "update" csv. This would need to be in a single program.

So my question is how would i go about this in python, do i need to use two phase commits or is there an another solution?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [psycopg2's `copy_from`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) method.  A rough example (change user, filename, separator, etc to your preference):

```
import psycopg2

def read_csv_file(file_name, table_name):
    con = psycopg2.connect("host=your_host dbname=your_db user=your_user")
    cur = con.cursor()
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        cur.copy_from(f, table_name, sep=",")
    con.commit()

csv_list = [
    ("file1.csv", "table1"),
    ("file2.csv", "table2"),
    ("file3.csv", "table3"),
]

for file_name, table_name in csv_list:
    read_csv_file(file_name, table_name)
```

Because `copy_from` appends to the table, you can repeat this for "update" csvs.

Comment: So would i need to write the with statement for every csv file or could i enter the path and select all csv files of the first phase and etc, or would it be a problem as the csv files need to populate around 8 tables?

Comment: One call to `copy_from` reads one CSV. So you could put it in a function and call that multiple times.